# invoke SAS from R via Integrated Object Model (IOM)

Tags: r, sas

It should be possible to invoke SAS from R via the Integrated Object Model ([IOM](http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/overview/iom_server.html)). I did some google searches but could not find much. I know that it is possible in theory and have done it in .Net but wonder if it is possible in R?

Comment: You could but I'd argue that's a complicated way to do it, and leaves you to deal with all kinds of issues like authentication and session management.  If you have access to the stored process server, calling SAS is as easy as calling a URL.  See here: http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/sas-as-service-easy-way-to-get-sas-into.html

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes a stored process server is another option - how would you handle security her though. Did you down vote btw?

Comment: Thanks this is another great way to integrate SAS. Feel free to post as alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd argue that using the IOM should generally be avoided, as it leaves you to deal with all kinds of issues like authentication and session management.

If you have access to the stored process server, calling SAS is as easy as calling a URL.  A guide to this technique can be found [here](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/sas-as-service-easy-way-to-get-sas-into.html), but essentially involves creating SAS code to stream data to the `_webout` fileref, and configuring this as an STP in SMC.

All your r code needs to do then is call the URL, eg via curl or whatever, to get the data you need.